# How to convert Date String to joda DateTime?

Tags: java, date, datetime, time

I have a date string "Wed Nov 20 00:00:00 IST 2019". How do I convert it to joda DateTime with the pattern "yyyyMMdd".

```
dateObject.setStartDate(new DateTime().plusDays(1).toString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Can't you switch to `java.time`?

Comment: @deHaar java 8. I Can't switch to java.time

Comment: Hmm... Java 8 has `java.time`... I guess you'd have to update several parts of your code if you wanted to switch to `java.time`, am I right?

Comment: yes that right. @deHaar

Comment: I am currently trying to figure out how to parse `"Wed Nov 20 00:00:00 IST 2019"` with a `ZonedDateTime`, but it seems unparseable... It seems to be the pattern `"E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"`, but that one doesn't work...

Comment: Can you show us a little bit more context? Where do you parse the date string? And: `setStartDate` expects a String again, right?

Comment: yes , i also got  the  same error. Now I  am trying to convert Date string to Date. After that Date to DateTime

Comment: @StefanHaberl yes it expects String. Instead of new DateTime() , I want to pass a custom date which i have in a String.

Comment: Is the 'IST' timezone fixed?

Comment: @StefanHaberl  I am getting this Date String from new Date(). yes it is taking local timezome.

Comment: Have a look at my answer, but why would you convert a `java.util.Date` -> `String` -> `JodaTime` -> `String`?. Use `new DateTime(new Date().toInstant())` instead

Comment: I dont want current date. I have two date string i.e startdate and enddate. and i am passing this to an API (which i am not allowed to change)

Comment: Parsing `IST` as a time zone abbreviation is risky because it may stand for Irish summer time, Israel standard time or India standard time, and we can't know which was intended, so chances are we are getting it wrong no matter what we try. Would it be possible for you to do something else?

Comment: Even though you are already using Joda-Time a lot, since Joda-Time cannot parse your string and java.time may be able, I see no harm in using java.time for this isolated task of converting from one string formst to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your String pattern is, that JodaTime does not recognize the 'IST' timezone. (See http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html for a list of supported time zones.)

If you always want to parse the date in the same time zone, you could use:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'IST' yyyy").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Indian/Mahe"));
DateTime parsed = DateTime.parse("Wed Nov 20 00:00:00 IST 2019", dateTimeFormatter);
```

Note that I have used `IST` as a string literal in the pattern format, i.e., this will only work if your date strings always includes the "IST" string.

To add fixed time zone information to your parsed date use `withZone` on the formatter. I picked a random Indian timezone known to JodaTime, "Indian/Mahe" in this case. Look up the one that matches your time zone in the list of supported time zones.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to make this code generic?

Comment: Generic in what sense? As commented above I would rather try to avoid parsing error prone date strings if you don't have to.